# Emacs + tern plugin on mac os x "no such file or directory: tern"

Tags: javascript, emacs, tern

I am using Mac Os X 10.11,
I have a fresh installation of Emacs(Emacsformacosx.com), and I am trying to install tern plugin for javascript.
I follow the simple commands:
-npm install tern -g
with el-get i install auto-complete and tern
I copy the short code snippet indicated from the tern site that activate tern-mode 
plus i added the path where tern is installed in my case (~/.emacs.d/el-get/tern/emacs)
and when I activate the tern-mode in emacs I get "No such file or directory tern" but from the terminal I can run it, so I cannot figure out what is the problem

Comment: I understood something more maybe can help you to help me. During el-get install he tries to do npm --production install. without any package to install. And it gives error. How to fix it I don't know. I am going to try it on linux tomorrow

Comment: Is tern in your `exec-path`? On OSX, consider using `exec-path-from-shell` https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Comment: It makes sense. So I am installing it, and I get that I set my "PATH" and "MANPATH" in my .zshrc, and it is true, and it asks to me to set them in .profile or .zshenv or .bash_profile, because i have oh-my-zsh installed i copied the line export PATH ****** in -zshenv that it didn't exist, but its not working. Is there something else i can do to have exe-path*** working?

Comment: Ok because I haven't been able to install successfully exer-path-from-shell, but thanks to rimero I understood which was the problem.
I fixed it in the following way:
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin")
that is the folder where everything installed with brew of npm goes.
Thank you.
I hope other people in troubles with OS X and Emacs find this page and fix their problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `tern` globally. In some cases it help to work. On run `tern_for_vim` check different types for start tern.js server: https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/blob/994ffbe783da36d67786b6c66a4bf784c5eab300/autoload/tern.vim#L15

For global install need run: `npm install -g tern`